# Can twittering-mode be used with GNU Social, and if so, how? If not, any alternatives?

Tags: major-mode

I have an account on GNUSocial, and I want to be able to control it from Emacs. However, I haven't found a way to do so yet. I can control my Twitter just fine through twittering-mode, and was wondering if it could be extended to control my GNU Social also. If not, is there a way I can control my GNU Social account through Emacs?

Comment: I think this may help - https://gnu.support/gnu-emacs/emacs-lisp/Emacs-Lisp-Send-Status-to-your-GNU-Social-instance-via-XMPP-or-Jabber-protocol.html